# Why the null hypothesis for AD is rejected for sample with positive skewness?

Tags: normal-distribution, normality-assumption

I know that the AD test for normality is very sensitive at the tail, but I notice that the null hypothesis for AD is rejected for samples with positive skewness, whereas it is not rejected for samples with negative skewness, is there an analysis for this?

Comment: Can you show us some examples of this?